# Update Facebooks Status using Python

Tags: python, facebook

Is there an easy way to update my Facebook status ("What's on your mind?" box) using Python code ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check out [PyFacebook](http://github.com/sciyoshi/pyfacebook/tree/master) which has a [tutorial](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/PyFacebook_Tutorial), from... Facebook!

Blatantly ripped from the documentation on that page and untested, you'd probably do something like this:

```
import facebook
fb = facebook.Facebook('YOUR_API_KEY', 'YOUR_SECRET_KEY')
fb.auth.createToken()
fb.login()
fb.auth.getSession()
fb.set_status('Checking out StackOverFlow.com')
```

Comment: Well, in my case fb object doesn't have set_status method. Why is that? Can you please throw some light on this?

Comment: same here.. fb foesnt have a object "set_status"

Comment: If your Facebook object doesn’t have a `set_status` method, open another question asking about it.

Answer (score 3):

The Facebook Developers site for Python is a great place to start.  You should be able to accomplish this with a REST call.

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Python

Comment: Hey!! This link seems to be expired .. Please suggest a new one or good source like that!